# JQuery Datatables plugin inside a JQuery UI Dialog not loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-ui-dialog

I have this code where url is some page with a table element with id="table"

```
$('#dialog').load(url).dialog({
    'modal' : true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        var table = $('#dialog #table').dataTable();
    },
    close: function(event, ui) { 
        $('#dialog').empty();
    }
});
```

The problem I am experiencing is that the datatable doesn't seem to load inside the open() event handler function. I have also tried putting the datatable code inside create() event handler function but to no avail. Very strangely when I add an alert() inside the open() function,

```
open: function(event, ui) {
    alert('test');
    var table = $('#dialog #table').dataTable();
},
```

it does load.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

might be that your selector is wrong ? try `$('#table').dataTable();`

or you can assign a class to your table , for example `class="mytable"` and change to the selector , like this:

```
$('.mytable').dataTable();
```

Comment: I have tried both "#table" and "#dialog #table" and it still does not work.